# What is ASPNET GUID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, guid

I have seen this code in ShoppingCart class in Music Store MVC3 tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store

```
// We're using HttpContextBase to allow access to cookies.
        public string GetCartId(HttpContextBase context)
        {
            if (context.Session[CartSessionKey] == null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.User.Identity.Name))
                {
                    context.Session[CartSessionKey] =
                        context.User.Identity.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Generate a new random GUID using System.Guid class
                    Guid tempCartId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    // Send tempCartId back to client as a cookie
                    context.Session[CartSessionKey] = tempCartId.ToString();
                }
            }
            return context.Session[CartSessionKey].ToString();
        }
```

Why is GUID needed? I am asking for somebody to explain what is it used for in this example.

Comment: Did you check the documentation? (or Wikipedia?)

Comment: And why do I need it? I am asking for somebody to explain what is it used for in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [part 8](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8) of that tutorial, under the heading "Managing the Shopping Cart business logic" - this explains the purpose of that code.

Basically, the GUID is used to uniquely identify a user, without forcing them to have logged in, so that the application can keep track of items that they have put into the shopping cart.

Answer (score 2):

A search for "C# GUID" would lead you to an easy answer: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx).

A GUID *represents a globally unique identifier* and it has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC in particular.

Please check documentation before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

A GUID is a globally unique identifier. See the following wikipedia entry:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier